# unable to change the items based on id and expected result should be in output format and it should return proper value with updated value

Tags: javascript

unable to change the items based on id and expected result should be in output format

```js
const items = [
        { id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "second" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
      ];
      const expectedOutput = [
{ id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "newvalue" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
]
      function getData(value, id) {
       return items.map((_each)=> {
         if(_each.id === id) {
           //need to update items with id=2
         }
       })
      }
      
      console.log(getData("newvalue", 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = [
        { id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "second" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
      ];
      const expectedOutput = [
{ id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "newvalue" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
]
      function getData(value, id) {
       return items.map((each)=> {
         if(each.id === id) {
           //need to update items with id=2
           return {...each, value}
         }else{
               return each }
       })
      }
      
      console.log(getData("newvalue", 2))
```